# How to use async/await with chai test?

Tags: node.js, chai, chai-http

I have a chai test that works without async/await syntax, but crashes with it. How to fix it?

The error is:

> error Error [ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN]: Listen method has been called more than once without closing.
> code: 'ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN'

Here is the same test with a working classic syntax and a non-working async/await syntax:

```js
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const api = chai.request(server).keepOpen();

// async/await => doesn't work
describe("GET /user/:id", () => {
  it("return user information", async (done) => {
    const res = await api
      .get("/user/123")
      .set("Cookie", "_id=567;locale=en");
    chai.expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
    done();
  });
});

// classic syntax => works
describe("GET /user/:id", () => {
  it("return user information", () => {
    api
      .get("/user/123")
      .set("Cookie", "_id=567;locale=en")
      .end(function (err, res) {
        chai.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: It looks like the problem isn't related to syntax. Somehow `chai-http` tries to spin-up the server twice hence you get "ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN" or maybe you already have the server running somewhere. 

The classic syntax "passes" because you don't use `done()` with it which you should do, [see the caveat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-http#caveat). What really happens is that the classic test fires a request, but doesn't wait for it to complete, so there're no assertions made, and as a result - no assertions no fails.

Comment: Yes, if I add done() in the end of the test, the latter also crashes with a `ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN`error. No, the server is not already listening. I just enter "yarn test".

Comment: It's hard to tell more without seeing the rest of the code. Somehow `server.listen()` is called few times.

Comment: Show the code of the server